# Remove NA and duplicates in a data frame column split by "\n" lines

Tags: r

I have a column in my data which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   ID_col                                                          
   <chr>                                                           
 1 "1020\nNA\nNA\n1020\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1020\n1020\n1020\n1020"
 2 "1651\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1651\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1651\nNA\n1651\nNA\nNA"    
 3 "1598\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1598\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1598\nNA\n1598\nNA\nNA"    
 4 "1141\nNA\nNA\n1141\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1141\n1141\n1141\n1141"
```

What I want to do is to remove all `NA` values and all duplicate values. (Keep only one occurance of the duplicated value)

Expected output for the 4 above would be:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   ID_col                                                          
   <chr>                                                           
 1 "1020"
 2 "1651"    
 3 "1598"    
 4 "1141"
```

Data:

```
structure(list(ID_col = c("1020\nNA\nNA\n1020\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1020\n1020\n1020\n1020", 
"1651\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1651\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1651\nNA\n1651\nNA\nNA", 
"1598\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1598\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1598\nNA\n1598\nNA\nNA", 
"1141\nNA\nNA\n1141\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1141\n1141\n1141\n1141", 
"NA\n835\n835\n835\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n835\n835\nNA\n835\n835", 
"1553\nNA\nNA\n1553\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1553\n1553\nNA\nNA", 
"1542\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1542\nNA\nNA", "NA\nNA\nNA\n1157\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1157\nNA\n1157\n1157", 
"NA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1498\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA", "NA\n958\n958\nNA\nNA\n958\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If all numbers in a given row are identical, `stringr::str_extract(ID_col, "\\d+")` should work. If not, `unique(stringr::str_extract_all(ID_col, "\\d+").`

Comment: Is the string like `123\nNA\nNA456` possible in your data?

Comment: I thought about using `strsplit` to first Split the strings into a list and then remove them from there.

Comment: Something like: `strsplit(d$ID_col, split = "\n")` and then `map(x, ~str_remove(., "NA"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use str_extract like this,

```
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- structure(list(ID_col = c("1020\nNA\nNA\n1020\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1020\n1020\n1020\n1020", 
                          "1651\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1651\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1651\nNA\n1651\nNA\nNA", 
                          "1598\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1598\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1598\nNA\n1598\nNA\nNA", 
                          "1141\nNA\nNA\n1141\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1141\n1141\n1141\n1141", 
                          "NA\n835\n835\n835\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n835\n835\nNA\n835\n835", 
                          "1553\nNA\nNA\n1553\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1553\n1553\nNA\nNA", 
                          "1542\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1542\nNA\nNA", "NA\nNA\nNA\n1157\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1157\nNA\n1157\n1157", 
                          "NA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1498\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA", "NA\n958\n958\nNA\nNA\n958\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))


df_example %>% 
  mutate(ID_col = str_extract(ID_col,"[:digit:]+"))
```

If you need multiple values

```
df_example %>% 
  mutate(ID_col = str_extract_all(ID_col,"[:digit:]+"))
```

Comment: Thats a little more simple tan my solution! `x <- strsplit(d$ID_col, split = "\n") %>% 
  map(., ~str_remove(., "NA") %>% stri_remove_empty(.))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
df$ID_col <- str_extract(df$ID_col, "\\d+")
    df
   ID_col
1    1020
2    1651
3    1598
4    1141
5     835
6    1553
7    1542
8    1157
9    1498
10    958
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID_col = c("1020\nNA\nNA\n1020\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1020\n1020\n1020\n1020", 
                                "1651\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1651\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1651\nNA\n1651\nNA\nNA", 
                                "1598\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1598\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1598\nNA\n1598\nNA\nNA", 
                                "1141\nNA\nNA\n1141\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1141\n1141\n1141\n1141", 
                                "NA\n835\n835\n835\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n835\n835\nNA\n835\n835", 
                                "1553\nNA\nNA\n1553\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1553\n1553\nNA\nNA", 
                                "1542\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1542\nNA\nNA", 
                                "NA\nNA\nNA\n1157\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1157\nNA\n1157\n1157", 
                                "NA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\n1498\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA", 
                                "NA\n958\n958\nNA\nNA\n958\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA\nNA"))
```